# c#: converting MAYA rotation (yUp, right handed, xyz order) to UNITY rotation (yUp, left handed, zxy order)

Tags: c#, matrix, unity-game-engine, maya, quaternions

I sadly don't have experience in matrix / euler calculations, but need to solve the following in c#, in Unity to the orientations match.

convert:

3 floats (orientation) of an object originating from Maya (yUp, right handed, xyz rotation order)

to:
quaternion rotation in Unity (yUp, left handed, zxy rotation order)

any input most welcome!
m.

Comment: You need `Quaternion.Euler`. Something like `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);`

Comment: thanks.. that 'something' is exactly the tricky part. ;-)

Comment: Do you have the option of passing the Maya data in some other form like a matrix? The handedness conversion and the euler conversion are really separate issues and splitting them makes things simpler

Answer (score 0):

`Quaternions` can be used to represent the orientation or rotation of an object. It depends on the Pivot of the `GameObject`. take a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html)

Comment: But I'm struggling to understand how I'm supposed to modify the original values to get to the new valid euler rotation from which I then can create the quaternion. This last part seems easy as there's a funtion for this.

Comment: Take an empty GameObject change its rotation to Your desire Rotation and then make the other Gameobject its child

Comment: You may want to look at [it](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7664/changing-the-pivot-point-of-meshes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution, with a hint to the following thread by a friend:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/right-hand-to-left-handed-conversions.80679/
The solution is posted by the user by the 'guavaman'.

The code I'm now using is of this structure:

- // translation
- var unityPosition = new Vector3(-maya_translation.x, maya_translation.y, maya_translation.z);
- // rotation
- var flippedRotation = new Vector3(maya_euler_rotation.x, -maya_euler_rotation.y, -maya_euler_rotation.z);
- var qx = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.x, Vector3.right);
- var qy = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.y, Vector3.up);
- var qz = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.z, Vector3.forward);
- var unityRotationQuaternion  = qz * qy * qx; // exact order!
- // scale
- var unityScaling = new Vector3(maya_scale.x, maya_scale.y, maya_scale.z);

Thanks for all the inputs and to 'guavaman'.